# How to detect charger ampere in android studio like Ampere

Tags: android, apk

How to detect charger ampere in android studio like Ampere
[image: Ampere]

Comment: What have you tried so far? The Android [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager) provides a lot of information about battery and charging please tell us what properties you have tried and why they don't give you the desired result.

Comment: @Robert Hi, BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW I tried this and I am getting right ampere but in only android 13. not getting right in 12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5 and this app giving right ampere of all phones.